# clip low resolution raster with polygon keeping exact boundary

Tags: postgis

For visual purposes (not analysis) I want to "clip" a low resolution raster using a shapefile with the exact boundary of the shapefile. ST_Clip doesn't seem to allow cutting across the inside of a pixel so it gives jagged edges since whole pixels are preserved. Is it possible to do this type of clipping without resampling to a higher resolution?

Clip maybe isn't the correct term to use which might be why I'm having trouble finding an answer. Something like a cookie cutter effect. In the end I just want to serve out a png of the bordered area.

Comment: Rasters are made of rectangular pixels. Only way that I can imagine for avoiding jagged edges is to resample and even that can only make the steps smaller. Some software may have an option for antialiasing which makes the edge more smooth for eye.

Comment: Make polygon with the hole and place your Raster underneath

Comment: @FelixIP  that sounds like something that could work. I don't see any documentation for something like ST_Mask is there a postgis function that you know of that does this kind of thing? It'd be nice if I could flatten the two layers into a png.

Comment: I don't now postgis. What I am suggesting is no more than visual effect.

Comment: @FelixIP I made an example of your advice in action using openlayers. It doesn't quite answer my original question, but may work for what I need. https://codepen.io/jeffswitzer/pen/WEVNZq

Comment: How did you solve it @apricity?

Answer (score 1):

I would vectorize the raster before "clipping" it. The vectorize/clipping operation in PostGIS is actually ST_Intersection(raster, geometry):

```
SELECT (gv).* 
FROM (SELECT ST_Intersection(rast, geom) gv
      FROM rastertable, vectortable
      WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, geom))
```

If your raster is very big in terms of number of pixels or covers an extent much bigger than the vector coverage, you would significantly gain in performance if the raster was tiled. Use the -t and the -I option when loading with raster2pgsql or use ST_Tile() and CREATE INDEX if you want to retile an already loaded raster.

I don't know any GIS package capable of cutting pixels. It always take all (pixel) or leave all.